# Getting Cron to run scheduled jobs with Drupal 9 in cPanel

Tags: cron, scheduled-job, drupal-9

I am trying to setup cron to run job.execute that I have setup in CiviCRM scheduled jobs. Drupal

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#cron

> Cron setup¶ In order for the scheduled jobs configured within the
> CiviCRM UI to run automatically, you'll need to configure a cron job
> which executes the Job.execute API call.

I have seen other examples but...
http://mydomain.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php as shown in other examples does not exist on my site.

The only cron.php I have found is in the following location:
/home/user/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/bin/cron.php

My site is in this location
/home/user/public_html/

CiviCRM settings are in this location
/home/user/public_html/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php

using the crontab method what would the  be to execute my scheduled job?

*/5 * * * * <job.execute>
*/5 * * * * job.execute
*/5 * * * * <something_something_job.execute>

I know these are not correct, what is the correct command? These instructions were not specific on how to get this working unless I am missing something right in front of my face...

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this `drush` or `cv.phar`. Detailed instructions for either can be found here:

https://civihosting.com/blog/how-to-make-a-cron-job-for-civicrm/

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cli.php -u <cpanel admin username> -p <cpanel admin password> -e Job -a execute
```

Comment: Iowa boys solution will not work as the cron file in no longer on that path in Drupal 9.